# Core data model not finding auto-generated entity classes after upgrading to XCode 6.3.2 (using Objective-C rather than Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode6

Today I upgraded to XCode 6.3.2.  I have a single XCode project that generates a number of different apps.  Each app is a different compile target.  All apps use the same core data model. There are 4 versions of the core data model.  The lastest one is the current one. The core data model has been used to auto-generate Objective-C entity classes.  Those entity classes are included in each of the different compile targets. The app has no Swift code in it.  Everything is implemented in Objective-C.

The apps still compile and begin to execute.  However, they crash as soon as the core data system gets loaded.  The app crashes with message:

`[GGPDescriptionMapping setKingdom:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GGPDescriptionMapping setKingdom:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`

The apps compiled and ran fine using the old version of xcode and the latest core data model.  With the new version of xcode, even though the latest version of the core data model is selected in the xcode interface as being the current data model, an older data model is being used in the compiled apps, triggering the kinds of problem described above.

Comment: Can't you just re-create the NSManagedObject classes?

Comment: That was one of the first things I did but no luck.  Still investigating the problem - it looks as though the latest version of xcode is using an older version of the data model than the one that has been selected as the currently active data model version.  Still investigating why that would be but in the meantime, changing the current data model version to an old one, running the app, watching it crash.  Deleting the app from the device or simulator then changing the current data model version back to the latest one and running the app again solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the current data model version to an old one, run the app, watch it crash again. Delete the app from the device or simulator (may not be necessary?) then change the current data model version back to the latest one using the xcode interface and run the app again. This managed to convince xcode 6.3.2 to use the right data model again.